Wait unti the master data is loaded in react js similar to resolved in angular
In my rect application I want load some master data from the ser that I will be putting in session storage and will be using throughout the user session without re-calling the server api.
I do not want to re-render the form based on the data loaded, I specifially wants to load all the data first and then render the form or do anything in the application
However this felt me like a general requirement anybody can have but I could not find anything that I exactly needs.
The solutions that I found from are

Using useEffect hook - But that will not wait for data to be loaded.
Using componentWillMount method but this method is deprecated and also if I am not wrong it does not allow async/await
Using componentDidMount method - But this again tries to re-render the form after the data is loaded

I referred these links
https://sergiodamm.medium.com/how-to-fetch-data-before-rendering-in-react-js-updated-584c3e65c175
https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/8747/react-lifecycle-methods-render-and-componentdidmount
React Router wait for resolve
Is there a possibility to achieve this in reactjs in some standard way?
Like

There is always going to be 2 renders for some component, but it doesn't need to be the form component. You can split your code into one component responsible for loading the data, and one or more that only render once the data is loaded. For example:
const Loader = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Insert code to load the data, then call setData and setLoading
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; // Or null if you want to display nothing
  } else {
    return <MyForm data={data} />
  }
}

const MyForm = ({ data ]) => {
  // Insert code that uses the data. The data will exist on the first render.
}

If you're using a particular library for routing, you can check their documentation to see if they have implemented something like this for you.  For example, react-router has the loader prop.

One can also use libraries that provide hooks just for this, e.g. useFetch https://use-http.com
